# What is the difference between driver.findElement() and driver.findElements()?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In `driver.findElements()` we get another function for finding `size()` which is not available in `driver.findElement()`.
Is it the only difference?

Comment: The answer is in the documentation: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By) .... `Returns: A list of all WebElements, or an empty list if nothing matches` ...think about it logically: you can check the `size` of a collection but how can you check the `size` of a single item?

Answer (score 6):

`driver.findElement()` returns first matching element with specified locator and `driver.findElements()` returns all(array of) matching elements with specified locator.

Answer (score 1):

`findElement` throws `NoSuchElementException` if no matching elements are found while `findElemetns` don't throw any such exception.
`findElement` will return first matched element and wont look further match while `findElemets()` will look for all possible matching elements. This do have impact on performance

Answer (score 0):

1. `findElement` is used to find the first matching element with the specified locator in the HTML page.
2. `findElement`'s return type is WebElement.
3. `findElement` will throw an error if the specified locator is not find in the loaded web page.