# java.lang.ClassCastException while Fetching number of rows and columns from Dynamic Webtable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, classcastexception

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

    public class WebTable {


    public static void main(String args[])throws ParseException{
    WebDriver wd;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium-2017\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    wd = new ChromeDriver();
    wd.get("http://money.rediff.com/gainers/bsc/daily/groupa");

    List<WebElement> col = (List<WebElement>) wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/thead/tr/th"));
    System.out.println("No of cols are : " +col.size());
     List<WebElement> rows = (List<WebElement>) wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]"));
     System.out.println("No of rows are :" +rows.size());
     wd.close();
    }
    }
```

Getting Below exception :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233) on port 44959
Only local connections are allowed.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at WebTable.main(WebTable.java:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findElement` returns a `WebElement`, which cannot be cast to a List of WebElements. Remove the cast `(List<WebElement>)` and use `findElements()` (with an 's') instead.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084193/what-is-the-difference-between-driver-findelement-and-driver-findelements) and this [tutorial](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/findelement-and-findelements-command/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You have to take care of a couple of things here as follows:

1. You are trying to `findElement()` as in `wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/thead/tr/th"));` which will return only **one** `WebElement`. Next you are trying to cast `WebElement` to `List<WebElement>` which the Java Compiler is complaining about as **`Type safety: Unchecked cast from WebElement to List<WebElement>`**. See snapshot below:

[image]

2. So instead of casting as in `(List<WebElement>) wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/thead/tr/th"));` we will use `findElements()` method and directly create a `List<WebElement>` as follows:

   ```
   List<WebElement> col = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/thead/tr/th"));
   ```
3. We will take the same approach for `List<WebElement> rows` as well but we have to change the `xpath` to get the count of `rows` as follows:

   ```
   List<WebElement> rows = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td/a"));
   ```
4. So your final code block will look like:

   ```
   package demo;

   import java.util.List;

   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

   public class Q45393541_rediff {

       public static void main(String[] args) {


           WebDriver wd;
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
           wd = new ChromeDriver();
           wd.get("http://money.rediff.com/gainers/bsc/daily/groupa");
           List<WebElement> cols = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/thead/tr/th"));
           System.out.println("No of cols are : " +cols.size());
           List<WebElement> rows = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td/a"));
           System.out.println("No of rows are :" +rows.size());
           wd.close();

       }

   }
   ```
5. Output on the console would be:

   ```
   No of cols are : 5
   No of rows are :182
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! Debanjan. After adding "s" I am getting desired o/p.Yes it works for me

Comment: @karishmayadav It wasn't only about `adding "s"`. You had to remove the casting & construct a unique `xpath` for `findElements()` to work :) Thanks